# create function in javascript to enable/disable input base on select

Tags: javascript

I have code that enable/disable input base on the selection and it work. and i realize to make it a function so i can use it easily when i need it. so this is my current code.

**script**

```
function ed(select, input){
    var $select= $(select),
        $input = $(input);
    $select.change(function() {
        if ($select.val() == 'Others') {
            $input.removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $input.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
        }
    }); //.trigger('change'); // added trigger to calculate initial state
        }
```

**html**

```
<form>
  <select id="trigger" change="ed('trigger', 'show-hide')" >
    <option>text here</option>
    <option>text2 here</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" value="" id="show-hide" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `id` selectors should be prefixed as `#YOUR_ID`

`change` handler will get attached every time `ed` function will get invoked.

Avoid using `inline-event-binding`

Try this:

```js
var $select = $('#trigger'),
  $input = $('#show-hide');
$select.change(function() {
  if ($select.val() == 'Others') {
    $input.removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $input.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="trigger">
    <option>text here</option>
    <option>text2 here</option>
    <option value='Others'>Others</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" value="" id="show-hide" />
</form>
```

**Using your approach:**

```js
function ed(select, input) {
  var $select = $('#' + select),
    $input = $('#' + input);
  if ($select.val() == 'Others') {
    $input.removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $input.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
  }
}
ed('trigger', 'show-hide');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="trigger" onchange="ed('trigger', 'show-hide')">
    <option>text here</option>
    <option>text2 here</option>
    <option value='Others'>Others</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" value="" id="show-hide" />
</form>
```

**Note:** `onchange` should be attribute to listen change event over select element not `change`

**Edit:** In your current code, both `inline` and `javascript` event binding is implemented which will result in unexpected output..

Comment: i just want to make a function so i can re used it whenever i want without touching the javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105342/discussion-between-jhunlio-and-rayon-dabre).

Comment: it works now in one set of select and input that hide but when i apply it to another set of select and hidden input using onchange="ed('id_here', 'id_here_hide')" it not working..

Comment: thank's for your patient working with my problem i got working now thank

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
 change="ed('trigger', 'show-hide')"
```

with

```
 change="ed('#trigger', '#show-hide')"
```

As [Rayon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35789366/1984039) above mentions, you need to pass id selector.

this is the [whole working code](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/zw5ogwgq/4/)

```
<select name="state" class="select" onchange="ed('#state', '#province')" id="state">
    <option value="something">Something</option>
    <option value="Others">Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="province" class="text" id="province" />
```

Note that above `change` is replaced with `onchange`

```
function ed(select, input)
{
    var $select = $(select),
    $input = $(input);
    if ($select.val() == 'Others') {
        $input.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $input.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
    }
}
$(document).ready( function(){

   ed('#state', '#province');

} );
```

Comment: @jhunlio can you share a fiddle?

Comment: @jhunlio there were multiple problems with your code, try this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/zw5ogwgq/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105340/discussion-between-jhunlio-and-gurvinder372).

Answer (score 1):

**Script :**

```
function enableDisable(selectName, inputName){
     var selectVal = $("select[name='"+selectName+"']").val();
     if(selectVal == 'Others'){ 
          $("input[name='"+inputName+"']").removeAttr('disabled');
     }else{
          $("input[name='"+inputName+"']").attr('disabled','disabled').val('');
     } 
    }
```

**HTML :**

```
<form>
  <select name="trigger" change="enableDisable('trigger', 'show-hide')" >
    <option value = "1">text here</option>
    <option value = "Others">Others</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" value="" name="show-hide" />
</form>
```

Comment: Extremely sorry for the late reply. Just replace 'change' to 'onchange'.

<select name="trigger" onchange="enableDisable('trigger', 'show-hide')" >